# Authentication and Authorization of HTTP API in Play Framework

Tags: oauth, playframework

I am building an API using the Scala version of the play framework. Some of the endpoints will contain confidential data but I am not sure how exactly to secure this.

Secure social (http://securesocial.ws/guide/configuration.html) is a library that I've been looking at but it seems oriented around websites and logging in with OAuth providers.

In this case it seems like I need to be an OAuth provider. Or is it possible that I can allow users to login with a provider, say Twitter? But then how would that work? The documentation around OAuth seems to be incredibly awful.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way to manage tokens. I would recommend building a token system, that would distribute and manage access token use. You can have one per user, or use a different system.

Then for each endpoint, you would have a wrapped action to secure the API.

```
case class SecuredAPIRequest(request:Request[AnyContent]) extends 

WrappedRequest(request)

trait SecuredController{
  import play.api.mvc.Results._

  //This takes an action for a request, and checks to see if the apiKey equals or API_KEY
  def SecuredAPIAction(f:SecuredAPIRequest => Result) = Action{
    request =>
      request.body.asJson.map{ jsValue =>
        (jsValue \ "apiKey").asOpt[String] match{
          case Some(key) if validKey(key) => f(SecuredAPIRequest(request)) //We are clear to go, execute our function. 
            // NOTE: validKey would be a function that checks the key against our DB ensuring that it is valid.
          case None => Forbidden

        }

      }.getOrElse(Forbidden)
  }
}
```

What SecureSocial does is route security request to the authentication service ( Twitter, Facebook, etc ), and uses their token as security. This would not work as an API, because it would be impossible to redirect users for auth.

Comment: Thanks for that. Conceptually you don't really explain tokens that much so I couldn't go and build something from that advice. Even just a link to others would be good enough.